# Package keyval Error: issn undefined (using biblatex-chicago.sty)

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I get the following error message when using XeLaTeX, Biber, and `biblatex-chicago`:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/biblatex-chicago.
sty:101: Package keyval Error: issn undefined.
```

The error is not fatal: if I press return, the PDF is still produced successfully. But I would rather make this disappear since it disrupts my workflow.

Question: what does this error mean, and how can I make it go away?

Comment: That means that the package does not know that option. You should show us a MWE with bibliography.

Comment: Ignoring errors is never a good idea. Do you mean `isbn`?

Comment: There is no `issn` option. The ISSN obeys the `isbn` switch that naturally also controls the ISBN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @moewe's comment, I realized what I was doing wrong: in calling the `biblatex-chicago` package, I had wrongly entered "`issn=false`" as one of the options. As @moewe points out, "there is no `issn` option."

So the solution is simply deleting `issn=false`.